# I am not able to understand this anomaly in Python

Tags: python

If try to change an element inside a globally declared array I get the desired result in this code:

```
a = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]


for r in a:
    for c in r:
       print(c,end = " ")
    print()
print()
def changeValue(ch):
   a[0][0]=ch
ch=input("Please enter a character\n")
changeValue(ch)
for r in a:
    for c in r:
       print(c,end = " ")
    print()
print()
```

But in the following code, I don't get the desired result ,i.e, the element at a[0][0] doesn't change

```
a = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
for r in a:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
print()
def enterSymbol(pos,ch):
    if pos==1:
        a[0][0]=ch
    elif pos==2:
        a[0][1]=ch
pos=input("Enter a position\n")

enterSymbol(pos,'X')
for r in a:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
```

Please help

Comment: Your `pos` is a string and can not be equal to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pos in input is always a string. That is why it will not go into the if conditions in enterSymbol (string compared to int).

```
pos = int(input("Enter a position"))
```

Replace this with the pos and it should work

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function returns a string, not a number:

```
>>> pos=input("Enter a position\n")
Enter a position
1
>>> pos
'1'
>>>
```

So this condition:

```
if pos==1:
```

is never True.

One way to solve your problem is to change your code to:

```
pos=int(input("Enter a position\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python understands your entry input as a char, not an integer.
You can for example replace your `if pos==1:` with if `pos=='1':` and that will work.